# TopLinks Do not show up

Tags: navigation, toplinks

the TopLinks navigation does not show up at all in my template.

in page.xml I have

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

in block

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
```

and in my header.phtml I have

```
<?php echo $this->getHtml('top.links') ?>
```

It does not show up at all, what else could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `getHtml` function uses the alias from the `as` attribute, rather than the `name`. The template should therefore be:

```
<?php echo $this->getHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

**Update:** you should basically have something roughly along the lines of:

`page.xml`

```
<default>
    <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
        <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    </block>
</default>
```

`page/html/header.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

Comment: hmm I tried this too but it didn't make any difference. The whole block doesn't load according to the inline hints. Is there some configuration I could have f*cked up? Installation is relativeley fresh So there is not much I have changed.

Comment: I updated my post a little. If this is basically what you have and it isn't appearing, the most likely issue is you need to clear your cache, the layout xml is cached.

Comment: This didn't work - cache is deactivated, cleared it nonetheless.. :-(